# how to shrink KVM hard drive image

Tags: kvm

When I copy the hd image from one machine to another one, the file become the full size. Is it possible to shrink it to its actual size? I have google a lot but nothing found. Hope someone give me clue. Thanks!

Leo

Answer (score 2):

Images can be sparsed, and your cp might not respect that for various reasons. I would:

- check the real file usage (du -sh vm.img or qemu-img info vm.img)
- use qemu-img convert -S to recreate a sparse image
- convert to qcow2 to have growing and versatile image instead